# Firebase Add iOS App Error - There was an unknown error while processing the request. Try again

Tags: ios, firebase

I'm trying to add a new iOS app in my project on Firebase console and I'm getting this generic error.

> There was an unknown error while processing the request. Try again.

I've tried to login again, didn't work. Also tried on several different browsers, didn't work too.

My project has just 23 apps and the same problem does not happens when I try to add a new Android App.

Are someone facing the same problem? What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me, I just signed out from Firebase/Google account and completely signed out of chrome and signed back in again. This worked.

The project was already created. So I just had to click on it, or you could try using another browser/device

If that won't work, try deleting some unused, preferably IOS, projects from the firebase console AND https://console.cloud.google.com/

Comment: @BrenoMacena what, even trying a different browser/computer all together?

Comment: Yes. The same problem does not happens with Android apps.

Comment: @BrenoMacena I'd try to delete a project that you no longer use, preferably and IOS project and try again. Make sure it's a different package name and ID from any other projects you've had on your console (even deleted projects)

Comment: I did remove several apps already (iOS and Android). I had 64 apps registered in my project, now I have just 23. 8 iOS Apps.

Comment: @BrenoMacena make sure you remove them from console.cloud.google.com as well, it takes up to a week for it to be fully deleted I think so you might have to wait.

Comment: Yes, the apps were fully deleted. I had to report the bug on Firebase support.